# C# Combo Box Only Sets in Debug

Tags: c#, debugging, combobox

I have been writing an application in C# (VS Express 2015) and have a combobox I want to pre-populate with a saved value.  I can't seem to get the combobox to take the value I try to set it to.  I created a new project just to demonstrate this error.

The main code is below.  Another file declares the tableLayoutPanel. The drawComboBox function should add a combo box to the panel with the given selected option and row.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        drawComboBox(Options.Blue, 0);
    }

    public enum Options
    {
        Unset,
        Blue,
        Yellow,
        Red
    };

    private void drawComboBox(Options SelectedOption, int row)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox colorCombo = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        colorCombo.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options));
        colorCombo.Name = "colorCombo";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(colorCombo, 0, row);
        colorCombo.SelectedItem = Options.Yellow;
    }
```

The weird part is if I run the program in normal debug mode or single step through it the combo box will always show "Unset," but if I break before the color is set and open the colorCombo item in the Locals debug window then step through it, it will be set correctly.  This makes it more than a pain to figure out what is going on given that looking at the problem in the debugger solves it.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas, thanks.

Comment: Data binding, like many things in .NET, is done lazily.  When it has to be done.  Delayed until the underlying native combobox is actually created.  Which you indeed force by looking at the Items property in the debugger.  Or by adding `var dummy = colorCombo.Handle;` before the assignment.   Sane way to do it is in the Load event.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is happening but I can tell you how to fix it -

please change the sequence of steps in your draw function like this & it will work fine.

```
 private void drawComboBox(Options SelectedOption, int row)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox colorCombo = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        colorCombo.Name = "colorCombo";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(colorCombo, 0, row);

        colorCombo.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options));
        colorCombo.SelectedItem = Options.Yellow;


    }
```

It seems its dependent on the sequence of these 2 lines of code

This combination gives "unset"

```
        colorCombo.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(colorCombo, 0, row);
```

if you reverse it, it works

```
  this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(colorCombo, 0, row);
        colorCombo.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Options));
```